# Rotated text in <td> is not showing properly in Windows Internet Explorer 8 (IE8)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, html-table

I have coded a PDF file into HTML. You can see it from this link: http://akibslab.com/mike

There are some text in `<td>` which is rotated by CSS3 transform element. The CSS code for rotating text is:

```
.vertical_text {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

The problem is the text is not showing properly in IE8, text is going out of the `<td>`. You can see it from the screenshot.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDvfw.png)

Comment: You still need to support IE8?  I'm so sorry, man :(

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you very much for your response. But what can I do because its looking odd.

Comment: Do you need more than English text? ... If no, make an image out of the text for IE8

Comment: @MaratTanalin Thank you very much for you help. Its working fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a fixed width for the element, add a nested element, and apply IE8’s rotation to the nested element instead of the current element.

But given the IE8’s negligible market share, it’s currently enough just to provide a reasonable fallback styling for IE8.